# Is the order of an associative array guaranteed in PHP?

Tags: php

When I perform a foreach loop over an associatve array in php, the order in which it is performed is the order in which it is defined.

For example:

```
$arr = array("z" => "z", "a" => "a", "b" => "b");

foreach($arr as $key => val)
  print("$key: $val\n");
```

Outputs:

```
z: z
a: a
b: b
```

Whereas

```
$arr = array("a" => "a", "b" => "b", "z" => "z");
```

Outputs:

```
a: a
b: b
z: z
```

So my question is then: is this behavior defined at a specification level? Can I have reasonable certainty that this behavior will not be changed in future versions of PHP?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered
>   map. A map is a type that associates
>   values to keys. This type is optimized
>   for several different uses; it can be
>   treated as an array, list (vector),
>   hash table (an implementation of a
>   map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more.

and

> Arrays are ordered. The order can be
>   changed using various sorting
>   functions.

So you can be certain (at least currently) that the order will be maintained. I would be very surprised if this behaviour were to change because it is clearly stated and because of this there will be a huge amount of code that relies on it.

Comment: Thanks! For whatever reason, I glossed over that - probably when I was still thinking that it didn't apply to associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This will never change.

Comment: Those are not the changes you are looking for. *does a Jedi hand wave*

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays are always ordered, and the easiest and fastest way to iterate the array is just going from the first element to the last one (so there is no good reason to change the behavior for foreach()), you can be reasonably sure that this behavior will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions seems like you came from programming in Perl where "arrays" are not guaranteed to be in the order you created them. But in PHP it has always been ordered and will always be, otherwise a lot of code will break.