# Returning first x items from array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to return first 5 items from array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 311, accepted):

[`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) returns a slice of an array

```
$sliced_array = array_slice($array, 0, 5)
```

is the code you want in your case to return the first five elements

Comment: but this will not work with associative arrays. the keys get lost.

Comment: @ESCOBAR: associative arrays don't necessarily have an order, they only map keys to values; so "values 3 to 7" doesn't really make sense anyway …

Comment: right, but in this case it is unrelated to the order. it is just about the first 5 items. and you can't use array_slice here.

Comment: @ESCOBAR: there are no **first** items if you don't have a defined order. "First" only works if you can tell which item comes before or after other items. But just for the fun of it, you can re-combine the keys with the values of the array (although there is still no defined order): `array_combine(array_slice(array_keys($array), 0, 5), array_slice($array, 0, 5))`

Comment: ok you are taking it very strict with the "first 5 items". But what do you get (or call it) if you iterate the array and stop it after the 5th item? You will allways get the same 5 items. you know what i mean?

Comment: @ESCOBAR: see my previous comment. It will get you the first 5 keys + values. Seems like that associative arrays in php [have a defined order after all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/950975/112968)

Comment: Note that array_slice() is NOT passed by reference. So if you wanted to overwrite your array with the truncated array, it would be: `$array = array_slice($array, 0, 5);`

Comment: @darkhorizon: "`array_slice` **returns** a slice of an array". But I will edit my answer to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @ESCOBAR if preserve_keys is set to TRUE, keys remain

Comment: Just remind that if the offset is larger than the size of the array, an empty array is returned.

Answer (score 13):

[array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else:

```
$input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
array_splice($input, 5); // $input is now array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

From PHP manual:

```
array array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length = 0 [, mixed $replacement]])
```

If **length is omitted, removes everything from offset to the end of the array**. If length is specified and is positive, then that many elements will be removed. If length is specified and is negative then the end of the removed portion will be that many elements from the end of the array. Tip: to remove everything from offset to the end of the array when replacement is also specified, use count($input) for length .

Comment: the syntax to return first 5 elements is

     array_splice($input, 5)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs As per php.net, "If length is omitted, then the sequence will have everything from offset up until the end of the array." Answer's bolded text states exactly the opposite.

Comment: @Kalko: you're probably looked at the wrong page. My copy-pasted statement is still valid: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs true mate, I had page for array_slice and didn't notice your answer was about array_splice... my bad :D

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to output the first 5 elements, you should write something like:

```
<?php

  if (!empty ( $an_array ) ) {

    $min = min ( count ( $an_array ), 5 );

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($value in $an_array) {

      echo $value;
      $i++;
      if ($i == $min) break;

    }

  }

?>
```

If you want to write a function which returns part of the array, you should use array_slice:

```
<?php

  function GetElements( $an_array, $elements ) {
    return array_slice( $an_array, 0, $elements );
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why would you wrap the existing `array_slice()` that already does the job into this unnecessary function that adds overhead and no value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice function, but do you will use  another values? or only the first 5? because if you will use only the first 5 you can use the LIMIT on SQL.

Answer (score -4):

A more object oriented way would be to provide a range to the #[] method.  For instance:

Say you want the first 3 items from an array.

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

numbers[0..2] # => [1,2,3]

Say you want the first x items from an array.

numbers[0..x-1]

The great thing about this method is if you ask for more items than the array has, it simply returns the entire array.

numbers[0..100] # => [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: But php doesn't support ranges. Are you sure you aren't talking about ruby or something like that?

Comment: "A more object oriented way"? 
This answer has nothing to do with object oriented programming.