# How can I display only a certain numbers of items contain in an Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got this code in AS3

```
var products:Array;
var list:Sprite = new Sprite();
function complete(e:Event):void {
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
    for(var i:int = 0, l:int = products.length - 1; l >= 0; i++, l--){
    createListItem(i, products[l]);
        if(products.length >=10){
            next.visible=true;
        }
}
    showList();
}
```

It displays a list of all the products contains in my table database.

Now I added `if(products.length >=10){` and it's working.

I would like to add

```
`if(products.length >=10){` 
What shoud I put here for showing only 10 products. 
next.visible=true;
next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, show10Next);
}

function show10Next(event:MouseEvent){
What should I put here for showing the 10 next products ? 
}
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDIT**

With Aaron answer, here's what I did :

```
function complete(e:Event):void {
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
    feedbackText.text = "complete";
    showNext() ;
}
function showNext():void {
    var currentNumShowing:int = list.numChildren;
    var nextNumShowing:int = Math.min(currentNumShowing + 10, products.length);
    for(var i:int = currentNumShowing; i < nextNumShowing; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
    }
    next.visible = nextNumShowing < products.length;
}
```

So now how can I add  `next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,next10);` ?

(as I can't do `next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showNext);` because `showNext` is not a MouseEvent...)

Secondly, my code was displaying the products from the end to the beginning (`for(var i:int = 0, l:int = products.length - 1; l >= 0; i++, l--){`. How can I keep that ?

I've tried :  `for(var i:int = currentNumShowing, l:int = products.length - 1; i < nextNumShowing;l >= 0;  i++, l--){`
but it's not working (error 1084 expecting rightparen before semicolon and expecting semicolon before rightparen)

Comment: What's with the downvote ?? It's a legitimate question (and this question has been asked for php here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571427/returning-first-x-items-from-array)] or here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array) But never asked for AS3.

Comment: Unexplained down-votes are annoying and unhelpful. I think your question is not very clear. Do you want to load all the products and only *show* 10 at a time? Or do you to load 10 at a time from your server?

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I meant "load all the products and only show 10 at a time" (if it's possible).

Comment: I posted an answer, but actually there's another question: do you want to show 10 more items and keep the existing items, for example 10, then 20, then 30, etc, or do you want to show only 10 items at a time (pages), like items 1-9, then items 10-19, then items 20-29, etc?

Comment: Thx for the answer. The 2nd one ( only 10 items at a time (pages), like items 1-9, then items 10-19...etc)

Comment: Ok, based on that I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is show 10 at a time from a `products` array, you can create a function to show a slice of the array like this:

```
const itemsPerPage:uint = 10;

var currentPageIndex:int = 0;

function displayPage(pageIndex:int):void {
    list.removeChildren();

    currentPageIndex = pageIndex;

    var firstItemIndex:int = pageIndex * itemsPerPage;
    var lastItemIndex:int = Math.min(firstItemIndex + itemsPerPage, products.length - 1);
    for(var i:int = firstItemIndex; i <= lastItemIndex; i++){
        createListItem(i - firstItemIndex, products[i]);
    }
    next.visible = lastItemIndex < products.length - 1;
}
```

Then from your `complete` handler you can show the first page like this:

```
displayPage(0);
```

Your `next` button can have a click handler that displays `currentPageIndex + 1`, like this:

```
next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextClick);
function nextClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    displayPage(currentPageIndex + 1);
}
```

Similarly, you could `displayPage(currentPageIndex - 1)` to go back a page.

If you want to display from the end to the beginning of the array, I recommend that you just [reverse it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#reverse()): `products.reverse()`

Note that if your data is huge, just loading the JSON could take awhile. In this case you should paginate your JSON data itself to only load 10 at a time

Comment: Thx; So I've added `showNext()` in my JSON `complete` handler. But I can't call the same function on my next button as it requiers 1 arguments `event:MouseEvent` (as it's a button..). So how can I do to call this function each time I click on "next" ?

Comment: Perfect : Thx. But, just one thing..How can I do to display the products in a different order ? (the end to the beginning) Thx

Comment: Hmm just a problem with this code. It seems that `displayPage` is removing an item. If I have only 1 item, it doesn't appears... Any idea why ? (the problem come from `displayPage`, as if delete `displayPage(0);` from `complete`, the unique item is displayed. If I put it back, the unique item is not displayed.

Comment: Fixed. For loop condition should be `i <= lastItemIndex` to include the last index.