# Is the order of keys returned from array_keys the same as the order in the input array?

Tags: php

Given an associative array like the following,

```
$field_defaults = array(
  'id' => 0,
  'name' => 'new item',
  'desc' => '',
  'parent_id' => 0,
);
```

can I rely on `array_keys()` returning the keys in the order they were specified? Or, more precisely, since arrays in PHP seem to have a stable order, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950995/2077), are the keys returned by `array_keys()` in the same order as they appear in the input array? The [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) doesn't give any hints.

When I try this, they *seem* to respect the original order, but I would like to be able to rely on that behaviour.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TL;DR: Theoretically you can't count on it; for practical purposes IMO you can.

---

Since the docs do not guarantee the ordering then technically the correct answer would be "no, you can't count on that".

<sub>That's because theoretically the developers could have chosen to reserve themselves the option of changing the implementation at a future date so that it does not honor the existing order any more (perhaps to improve performance, or to gain some other benefit).</sub>

Now as a *practical* matter, we know that [the current implementation honors the ordering](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.1/ext/standard/array.c#3319) -- PHP arrays are ordered containers (there is a linked list of values among other things) -- and this is something you wouldn't ever expect to change.

If it did, the change would hint to a corresponding significant change in the internal implementation of arrays and that would in turn be likely to break lots of other code too. I don't see it happening any time soon.

Comment: Just a FYI for anyone reading this, as we found out today - you **cannot** count on this. It does not always respect ordering.

Comment: @Kyron could you provide some more details please?

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned, you could always pick one as the correct order and then reimplement the other function based on that. And if you care about consistency between the two calls, you probably are going to call both `array_keys` and `array_values` at the same time. So why not do both simultaneously? E.g., let's assume that the order of `array_keys()` is "correct". Then do:

```php
function arrayKV($arr) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    $values = array();
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $values[] = $arr[$key];
    }
    return array('keys' => $keys, 'values' => $values);
}
```

That way, you know that they are in the same order. Alternatively, you could provide the keys to use as the order:

```
function arrayValuesStable($arr, $keys) {
    $values = array();
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $values[] = $arr[$key];
    }
    return $values;
}
```