# More efficient way to sort unique values from array of arrays by occurrences in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the most efficient PHP way to get unique values from an array of arrays and sort them by number of occurrences from most frequent to least?

Example input array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => D
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => C
            [2] => D
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => F
            [2] => X
        )
)
```

Would result in this output array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C    // 3
    [1] => A    // 2
    [2] => D    // 2
    [3] => B    // 1
    [4] => F    // 1
    [5] => X    // 1
)
```

The alphabetical order of values with same number of occurrences is not important.

So far I'm merging the array of arrays:

```
$all_posts = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $results );
```

Then creating a new array where values become keys. And values are the number of times they occur in the original array of arrays.

```
$posts_by_count = array();
foreach( $all_posts as $apost ) {
    $posts_by_count[ $apost ] = 0;
    foreach( $results as $tag_posts ) {
        if( in_array( $apost, $tag_posts ) ) {
            $posts_by_count[ $apost ]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can sort by value

```
arsort($posts_by_count);
```

And create a new array where keys become values again.

```
$sorted_posts = array();
foreach($posts_by_count as $k => $v) {
    $sorted_posts[] = $k;
}

pprint( $sorted_posts );
```

What would be a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest I can come up with is to start with the `array_merge()`, but using the splat (`...`) to merge all of the arrays.  Then use the inbuilt `array_count_values()` to summarize the values and then `arsort()` to sort them...

```
$all_posts = array_merge(...$results );
$posts_by_count = array_count_values($all_posts);
arsort($posts_by_count);
```

This gives the output of...

```
Array
(
    [C] => 3
    [A] => 2
    [D] => 2
    [B] => 1
    [F] => 1
    [X] => 1
)
```

using

```
print_r(array_keys($posts_by_count));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => A
    [2] => D
    [3] => B
    [4] => F
    [5] => X
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simple, first iterate to count occurences, finally use `arsort()` to sort it by value in descending order:

```php
<?php

// sample data
$arr = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['A', 'C', 'D'],
    ['C', 'F', 'X']
];

// counting
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $subarr) {
    foreach ($subarr as $char) {
        $newArr[$char] = (!array_key_exists($char, $newArr))
            ? 1
            : $newArr[$char] = $newArr[$char] + 1;
    }
}

// sort by value in DESC order
arsort($newArr);

// To get exactly what you want (without counting) just iterate $newArr and writ is as a $flatArr
$flatArr = [];
foreach ($newArr as $index => $item) {
    $flatArr[] = $index;
}

// or with array_keys which _may_ be unstable @see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10336363/1066240
$flatArrArrayKeys = array_keys($newArr);

// output
$newArrHr = print_r($newArr, 1);
$flatArrHr = print_r($flatArr, 1);

echo "<pre>OUTPUT:

With count:
$newArrHr

As flat array:
$flatArrHr

As flat array with array_keys()
$flatArrArrayKeys
";
```

Comment: Did you use `foreach` instead of `array_keys` by design to get the $flatArr?

Comment: @oleg point for you, there's always place to improvement. Updated.

Comment: Thanks @biesior :) but really was just curious because some think `array_keys` might not be reliable with preserving order (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336363/is-the-order-of-keys-returned-from-array-keys-the-same-as-the-order-in-the-input)

Comment: @Oleg Actually never thought about it ;p for sure iterating like in the first step is secure, I'll update to show both ways. The best will be if you test them both and let us know.